# Vim Warning: Output is not to a terminal

Tags: linux, vim, perforce

I do not get why, by few weeks where I am not sure what has changed, I get a strange error when trying to execute this vim funcions:

```
function! P4diff()
       aboveleft 40new
       setlocal nomodified buftype=nofile nowrap filetype=diff
       %!p4 diff #
       setlocal nonu                                                                    
       setlocal
       readonly                                                                
       syntax on
    :endfunction
```

I get the error:

```
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
[51;1H"tmp.15529.64" [RO][converted] 119L, 2893C
"ProxyChain.java"                         [51;19H[converted] 115L, 2943C
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: Finished.
[51;1H
```

2 files to edit

Anyone knows why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `:{range}!` command to filter the lines through an external program, Vim sends the lines on stdin and redirects stdout to capture the output.

It looks like the `p4 diff` command that you invoke is internally using Vim (maybe as a pager), and that subordinate Vim instance is complaining with the mentioned warnings. You may want to disable paging (maybe there's a command-line argument or environment variable that controls this) when using `p4` non-interactively.